# MySQL summing verses and n biggest results

Tags: mysql, select, sum

I've a table looking more or less like that:

```
**Day**   | **Mileage**
----------------
1     | 13

2     | 2

3     | 25

4     | 15

5     | 20

6     | 8

7     | 17

8     | 12

9     | 16

10    | 5
```

How to write a SQL query:

1. Returning total mileage from the firts to the nth day without using php? For example, day 1:13, day 2: 15, day 3: 40.
2. How to get 5 biggest mileages without using limit?

Comment: What have you attempted?  Why can't you use `limit`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sum up:

```
select mday, (select SUM(miles) from mm s where s.mday <= mm.mday)  tot_miles
from mm;
```

For the 5 biggest mileage per day

```
select mday, miles from mm order by miles desc limit 5
```

Change the column names and table name to match yours.

Since you added the "no use of  limit", which is odd, you can try this:

```
set @r =0;
select * from (
select *, @r :=@r+1 as r from mm order by miles desc) e
where r<=5
```

Answer (score 1):

Since You do not want to use limit here is the tedious  way

1)

```
select sum(mileage) from xyz where day between 2 and 15;
```

2)

```
mysql> select @rownum:=@rownum+1 'rank',mileage
from (select mileage from xyzorder by mileage desc)mil,(select @rownum:=0)r
where @rownum<5;
```

Comment: This method does not require limits